# Sharedpreferencs with flutter to save color

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I want a container to be of a color,  that comes from sharedpreference or something like that! Is there a widget to solve this!! Or can I just do this with sharedpreference!! If I can! How?

Answer (score 10):

A better way is to save the `color.value`.

Use

```
final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
Color myColor = Color(prefs.getInt('color') ?? Colors.blue.value);
// change Colors.blue to a default color
```

to get the color, and

```
prefs.setInt('color', myColor.value);
```

to save a color.

Answer (score 3):

With flutter [SharedPreferences](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences) plugin you can only save `String, int, StringList, double, Bool`.

A work around would be to save the `RGBO` value of the color in `SharedPreferences`, this would work for Android and iOS.

**Step 1. Install the plugin**

`pubspec.yaml`

Add SharedPreferences to your `pubspec.yaml` file. Check the last version by clicking [here](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences).

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  shared_preferences: ^0.5.3+4
```

**Step 2. Save the RGBO value in SharedPreferences**

```
  void saveColor(int r, int g, int b, double opacity) async {
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    prefs.setInt('r', r);
    prefs.setInt('g', g);
    prefs.setInt('b', b);
    prefs.setDouble('o', opacity);
  }
```

**Step 3. Retrieve the value and create your color**

```
getColor() async {
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    final r = prefs.getInt('r');
    final g = prefs.getInt('g');
    final b = prefs.getInt('b');
    final opacity = prefs.getDouble('o');
    return Color.fromRGBO(r, g, b, opacity);
  }
```

Comment: How do I use the flutter/material.dart 's instance "Color" class & pass through the SharedPreferences ?

Comment: `SharedPreferences` only saves `String, int, StringList, double, bool` therefore you can not pass `Color` instance to `SharedPreferences`. The workaround is in the answer.