# how to save color in sharedpreferences

Tags: flutter, dart, sharedpreferences

i am trying to save Color in sharedpreference but it has only limited data type (String, int, double etc) i dont know

```
Future getColor() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    Color color = prefs.getString("color"); //error 
    return color;
  }

  Future setColor(Color themeColor) async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    await prefs.setString("color", (themeColor); //error
  }
```

}

Comment: Not sure if that's the issue, but you're missing a bracket here: `await prefs.setString("color", (themeColor);`. Should be `await prefs.setString("color", (themeColor));`.

Comment: this is not about the code actually, a type of color cannot be assign to type string or int thats the issue

Comment: This has already been answered here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58261036/sharedpreferencs-with-flutter-to-save-color

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I hope this code helps you. It can be written in a more beautiful way but I hope you get the idea.

```
//Convert the color to hex, Save it in preferences
var myColor = Colors.blue;
var hex = '#${myColor.value.toRadixString(16)}';
//save Hex value in sharedpreference.
```

```
//get the hex value from shared preferences and convert it into color.
Color yourColor= hexToColor(colorStringFromSharedPreference);

Color hexToColor(String code) {
  return Color(int.parse(code.substring(1, 7), radix: 16) + 0xFF000000);
}
```

Also as suggested in the comment, you can also store the int value of the color.

```
int myColorInteger = myColor.value
//store integer value in sharedpreference
```

and retrieving it and using Color's constructor

```
//retrieve intValue of color from sharedpreference and
Color myColor = Color(intValue)
```

Comment: You could make it simpler by storing myColor.value (which is an int) and retrieving the Color object with a constructor: Color(int).

Comment: That's true, I appreciate your suggestion @AzzamAlsharafi. The above solution just came spontaneously in my mind.

Comment: Future getColor() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    Color color = Color(prefs.getInt("color"));
    return color;
  }

  Future setColor(Color themeColor) async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    await prefs.setInt("color", themeColor.value);
  }
    }

Comment: This code is just fine. I think you have made some errors in initializing after you called these methods.

Comment: Color color = Color(await _prefs.getColor());
      if (login) {
        add(UpdateStateEvent(LoggedInState(theme: color ?? Colors.brown)));
      } else {
        add(UpdateStateEvent(LoggedOutState(theme: color ?? Colors.brown)));
      }
    });

Comment: The problem is you are already returning Color from getColor method. Change your function def to Future<Color> getColor. It would be more intuitive for you. Hope this helps. Cheers